# Remove all the popups in an application

Tags: apache-flex

How can we remove all the popups existing in an application?

Comment: What popups? What application? What language?

Comment: @Robusto: The "Flex" tag covers it.

Comment: This article about [closing popups in flex](http://blog.flexmonkeypatches.com/2007/10/04/flex-close-all-popups/) at Flex Monkey Patches Blog may be helpful.

Comment: interesting solution.  We don't typically use PopupManager for relatively obvious reasons... but just the same, I can't say I've ever used that 4th argument.  Good find.

Comment: @jeremy.mooer what are those obvious reasons? I use a Util method to create popups but it internally uses popupmanager.

Comment: Garbage collection was the main reason, though this was maybe a bigger issue in Flex2.  Passing an instance of the parent displayObject might cause for that parent object, or even the popup, to not get garbage collected.  If I use solely transitions and states, I have more control of eventListeners and I can make sure that the component/popup is very loosely coupled.  I'd much rather be the one to destroy the component and remove event listeners than depend on PopupManagerImpl's built-in removePopUp.

Comment: IMHO if your application can have lots of popups open at once, you should probably rethink its user interface.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2009/12/getting-all-the-popups-in-a-flex-application/) much useful.
It is as simple as iterating all objects and checking if isPopup!

Answer (score -1):

Based on the limited detail of your question, the best I can give you is that you could search the entire application for the code that initiates pop-ups with [ctrl]+[shift]+[f]